# how can I make sure that the user's answer is valid and if the answer isn't valid then ask the question again

Tags: c#

I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere, so what I want to do is first, ask the user a question such as "do you want to see this cool movie?" and if the user replies yes then I show them the movie and if they reply no then I move on. If the user replied with something other than yes or no, such as "fadlfjlashfashdf", I wanted to be able to ask the user "Please answer yes or no." until they answer yes or no. The problem is, I couldn't find a way to do that without making the code very confusing and long. Here is something that I tried:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to see this cool move?");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();

        while(answer.ToLower() != "yes" || answer.ToLower() != "no")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please type yes or no. ");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        if (answer.ToLower() == "yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ok");
        }
        else if(answer.ToLower() == "no")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("sure");
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, this isn't valid C#. If you fix your code, we might be able to help you better.

Comment: oh oops sorry I fixed it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your approach here is perfectly reasonable. In fact, it's almost exactly how I'd do it.

In general, if there's some condition that needs to be handled in a special way (like invalid input), and it can happen multiples times in a row (the user continues to give invalid input), then you're gonna have to use a loop of some kind.

Now, with that said, there's a bug in your code. Can you find it?

Comment: If the user gives `no` as their answer, then the first sub-condition of the `while(...)` loop evaluates to `true` (because `"no".ToLower() != "yes"`), but because it's part of a logical OR, the second sub-condition isn't evaluated at all, and the program enters the body of the loop. This isn't the desired behavior. You should use a logical AND (`&&`) instead of a logical OR (`||`). Does that make sense?

Comment: OH!! I get it now!! I just had to change the || to &&
thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `TryXxx` pattern made famous by calls like `double.TryParse` and `Dictionar<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue`.  First write a `TryXxx` method like:

```
static bool TryGetBooleanFromAnswerString(string answer, out bool isAffirmative)
{
    if (answer.Equals("yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        isAffirmative = true;
        return true;
    }
    if (answer.Equals("no", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        isAffirmative = false;
        return true;
    }

    isAffirmative = false;      //it's meaningless, but I need to set it to something
    return false;
}
```

Notice that I used the `string.Equals` overload that takes a `StringComparison` parameter - it says that "Yes", "yes" and "YES" are all equivalent.

Then I can write code like:

```
bool answerAsBool;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine(@"Wanna take a bath");  // I'm old enough to remember Pink Floyd

} while (!TryGetBooleanFromAnswerString(Console.ReadLine(), out answerAsBool));
Console.WriteLine($@"You answered with a {answerAsBool} answer");
```

Comment: By the way, the real advantage of this is if you want to do process user input more than once